# Owl carousel product gallery image in fotorama full screen

Tags: magento2

I have created a custom photo gallery with owl carousel for product image.
but now no more able to open image in fotorama full screen.
Is there any way so owl-carosel image click open in fotorama full screen?

Comment: No, there is no native way of doing that. If you're using owl carousel 2 you can create your own extension. It shouldn't be that hard to be honest.

Comment: Yes i was also thinking so.Thank you for your suggestion.